# HDMI display just stopped working

Tags: display, hdmi, kodi

I am using Ubuntu (Kodibuntu actually, which is a flavor of Trusty) and I connected my display via HDMI. This has been working for years but today the display just stopped working.

I can see the boot screen, navigate through the boot menu, etc, but when the system enter grub or Ubuntu boot, the screen just goes black and says there is nothing connected to it. I can connect to that pc via SSH normally.

I don't even know how to start debugging this. Anyone has any idea?

---

**Edit**

Got somewhere (it now displays a scaled image) with the following

```
gtf 1920 1080 25
xrandr -d :0 --newmode "1920x1080_25.00"  64.88  1920 1952 2144 2368  1080 1081 1084 1096  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr -d :0 --addmode HDMI1 "1920x1080_25.00"
xrandr -d :0 --output HDMI1 --mode "1920x1080_25.00"
```

But I need to do this every time I boot. How can I do something similar automatically?

Answer (score 0):

This can be a hardware problem, so if you have a dedicated graphics card with the driver installed, make sure the display is connected to it.

Also make sure that there isn't an issue with the Display (try connect it to another computer and see the results or try another HDMI cable).

Comment: If it were a hardware problem, how would I be able to see the BIOS menu and so on?

Comment: It is possible that the computer recognises the display as being connected but not through the graphics card. I had the same problem and I found out that my screen was connected to the motherboard straight away rather than through the graphics card, which let the screen be used in the BIOS but not in the OS interface.